# Custom JSON response from Policy-Based Authorization Being Overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I've made a custom policy requirement and handler. Its working fine and returning a 403 if they don't meet the requirement.

I'm trying to return a custom JSON object with a message about why the request failed authorization. Here is the code I'm using:

```
if (!_currentUserService.Permissions.CanGetSaleAnalysis)
{
    var mvcContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext;

    if (mvcContext != null)
    {
        var responseObj = ForbiddenResponseFactory.GetResponse(WorkbookAuthFailure.GetSaleAnalysis);
        mvcContext.Result = new JsonErrorResult(403, responseObj);
    }
}
else
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
```

It seems as if the cookie middleware is seeing the challenge result and overwriting the response so it doesn't contain my JSON message... What is the best way to handle this?